# Fallback intent for ambiguous utterances in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Is it possible to add fallback intent for those utterances which is not trained in my app?

I have added plenty of utterances to my app but if something user said and didn't match with any of the utterances then i want it to fallback and tell user that I am unable to find anything for you.

Right now I have 4 Intent:

GetNews
GetWeather
GetRecepie
GetInformation

Now I have utterance "Get me sports news" for the GetNews intent and I have "I want Chinese recepie" for GetRecepie. I have added as many utterances for the all the intent as much i can but i came across one utterance that is "Get me neighbour news", Now i do not have any newsType such as neighbour but i have handle in my code if newsType is undefined then show generic news. But when I command this utterance, it fall into GetRecepie intent. All 4 of my intent's utterances are starting with different words, nothing is matching with each other, then too why it is falling for GetRecepie instead of GetNews?

What is the solution for such scenario? Is there any way I can make a fallback something so that if any utterances are confused so it should go for the fall back? Or is there any other solution?

It is just not about the normal utterance but user might command "ABCDRIKHLFJ", then how to handle that.. right now everything is falling into GetRecepie.

For a solution, I have created an action file name LetItFallback and while validating GetRecepie, I replan it and pass the goal to fallback action.

```
action (GetRecepie) {
 type(Search)

  collect{
    input (receipeID) {
    type (ReceipeChoiceResult)
    min (Optional)
    validate{
      if(not exists(receipeID.name)){
        replan{
          intent{
            goal{LetItFallBack}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} 
output (RecepieResult) 
}
```

but i am getting error in simulator

`Unable to attach plan from 1.0.1-myAppID.api.GetRecepie#1.0.1-myAppID.api.RecepieResultreplan intent`

I am not sure what is wrong but if this solution is fine then how to resolve this error else please give me solution for the real issue.

Comment: please give me a solution.. it's been 3 days since asked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are overloading your capsule with very wide variety of services, recipe, news, weather and general search. Bixby capsules should have concise objective. You can split your capsule into 3 different capsules, recipe, news, weather and better not to create a generic "search" capsule. It is Bixby platform's job to "catch" any unhandled utterance and execute a fallback action.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is just an example, my capsule is something else and I can't make different capsule. If bixby will decide what utterance should go where then why it is falling to different intent

Comment: Okay, I understand your situation, thanks for clarifying that it is just an example. My answer holds true for given example. I suggest you to contact Bixby Official Support. There you can freely discuss your exact situation confidentially and confidently as that communication may come under NDA (not revealed to anyone) between you and Samsung. You may get personalized support as well. Just give it a try. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points to explore:

1. "User might command "ABCDRIKHLFJ" ": You should train Bixby to handle expected utterances rather than train it for unexpected inputs. If a user provides an unintended input, Bixby will request the input it needs.
2. Your capsule may be attempting to do too much. Depending on the
   nature of how GetNews, GetWeather, GetRecepie, and GetInformation
   interact with each other, it may be possible that your capsule is
   simply attempting to serve too many use cases. This results in Bixby
   understanding the contents of an utterance incorrectly and routing
   utterance information to the wrong Action. I would recommend that
   you look through the [Principles of Training](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.NL-and-Training#principles-of-training) found here as they
   explain what is required in order to ensure that Bixby can
   accurately understand utterances and route the correct information
   to the correct Actions within your capsule.

Comment: What is that error in simulator talking about... How to resolve that

Comment: And as I said the given example is just an example, I am working on something else which is not related to this... And by saying abcdefg doesn't mean exactly abcdefg, user can say anything, literally anything, how much utterance you can add. Somewhere it needs to fallback

Comment: It wouldn't need a fallback Action because Bixby would ask for the required inputs. For example, if your `GetNews` Action has a required `NewsType` input and the user does not provide this input, Bixby would request the required input with some form of "I need a NewsType to continue" dialog (which you can define via dialog files and macros) without any explicit coding done on your end.

Comment: is there anyway i can give you my capsule and show you exactly what is happening?

Comment: Please reach out to the support team using the "Contact Support" option in the "Help" dropdown menu in Bixby Studio. This will create a ticket where we can discuss your use case in greater detail.

Comment: Sure ... Will do

Comment: Two more questions are there... Please attend

Comment: Have raised the ticket.. please attend

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the other poster that said you are probably trying to do too much with the single app, I wanted to answer you question about fallback intents because I had the same one.

In order to handle unknown inputs, what I did was create a series of dialogs that matched against the inputs that were missing. Below is one of them.

`dialog (Elicitation) {
  match: type
  template("I didn't understand what type you were trying to say..")
}`